# Is my usage of this word correct?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-structure

> 'The **ambit** of his patience"

I'm not sure if I've used the word *ambit* correctly here. Could someone tell me what context it can be used in / examples to go with?

Comment: Have you tried any basic research with this? Because a quick google search provides the definition and examples of use.

Comment: I did, but it's pretty vague so I didn't really get the idea of the word? as in I know the meaning of it but I'm not sure how I should use it.

Answer (score 3):

You probably have, although you're short on context in the question for me to be absolutely certain. But why are you using ambit instead of something that A. your average audience member understands like limit, and B. is well enough defined that you as an author can tell from the sample you've given whether the word is correct or not? You appear to be making extra work for yourself and your readers.

Comment: This. It makes it look like pretentious, lazy writing (as in, you want to appear elite and you've just grabbed the thesaurus - that scene from Friends with Joey springs to mind)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use words you're not sure about.

There's an old, old anecdotal story about two men standing in front of a shop having a conversation.

One would say something, and the other would reply with -Evidently. - this went on for a long while during which all the second man would say was... - Evidently.

At a point in the conversation, the first man cried out - Evidently, evidently... YOU are evidently!

Offended, the second man retorted - NO!!! YOU are evidently!

The friendly conversation ended with a fistfight.